# mysql count per group with where clause

Tags: mysql

I have looked and found answers similar to what I have but none of those solutions work for me.  I have the following sql trying to group by wo_type and get a count of entries for each row.  But I only want rows included that meet the criteria.  While I am getting the groups the count is the same for every entry.  If I remove the where clause I get different counts but they include the entries I do not want.

```
select a.wo_type, count(*) from deinstall_bpm_work_orders a
left join deinstall_bpm b on a.task_id = b.id
where b.status = 'WORKING'
group by a.wo_type
order by a.wo_type
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test groupy also withb.status and avoiding the where so yoy can check the real count content

```
  select a.wo_type, b.status, count(*) 
  from deinstall_bpm_work_orders a
  left join deinstall_bpm b on a.task_id = b.id

  group by a.wo_type, b.status
  order by a.wo_type, b.status
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem = it seems I did not factor in one more selection criteria.  So my initial query was correctly reporting 742 for count but once I added the second selection criteria things now appear as I need them.